# Can a writer change the perspective of a story?

Tags: narrative, viewpoint

Is it a bad thing if someone writes a story in the third point of view, then he changes the whole story into the first point of view where the protagonist himself tells the story?

Comment: You might find The Art Of Fiction by John Gardner helpful in this regard

Comment: I suppose the question can be taken as a general one since the asker hasn't exactly limned for us the exact plot or structure of her story, and so I answered in general terms as well.Coming back to your question, the book I referred to has chapters on technique and plotting, which I am certain would help her develop a better perspective on how to fine-tune the structure of her story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the author, while revising their work, making that change.

And that's perfectly fine. It's a good idea, in fact, to try out different points of view. Try writing a section in first person just to see how it makes the story sound. Or read the whole thing to yourself as if it were first person. It might improve it or not. There's a lot of experimentation in writing.

Answer (score 0):

Most first person stories, as well as many third person stories, stay in a single character's perspective. In some point of view strategies, however, you can shift perspective. For example: ... Changing perspective also demands the reader readjust after being so invested in the character whose perspective came before.

Comment: You say "For example:" but where is the example?